# Select Group and Keys in NSDictionary

Tags: objective-c, nsmutabledictionary

I have an NSMutableArray inside a variable called **myMutableDictionary** in this format:

```
2 =     (
    4,
    6
);
3 =     (
    7,
    8
)
```

How I can select the number **4** inside the group **2**?

Comment: What does 2 correspond too? Do you have multiple arrays in this array or something?

Comment: I only have one array (one variable) inside my array I have others arrays as you can see...

Comment: The outer object is a *dictionary*, not an *array*.

Comment: Ok, well I'll tell you how to access an index in an array, hopefully you know whats going on.

Comment: Yes sorry, is a NSMutableDictionary...

Comment: Just to be more precise, you can't have an object inside a variable, variables just stores pointers to objects.

Answer (score 0):

Provided you have the correct object, you can access the first index in a few ways. All of these methods will provide the return value of 4 into the variable `num`.

Using the array objectAtIndex method:

```
NSNumber *num = [myMutableArray objectAtIndex:0];
```

Using literals:

```
NSNumber *num = myMutableArray[0]
```

Now, to populate `myMutableArray` from the dictionary, you need to pull it out.

```
myMutableArray = [dict valueForKey:@"2"];
```

or you could add all this together to do something like

```
NSNumber *num = [[dict valueForKey:@"2"] objectAtIndex:0];
```

Comment: And if I would to select the index 3 value 8?

Comment: Provided `myMutableArray` now points to `3`: `[myMutableArray objectAtIndex:1]`;

Comment: Is confusing to understand yet, In PHP the same array is as follows: [0] => '2'([0]=4,[1]=6), [1] => '3'([0]=7,[1]=8,[2]=5), In PHP if I like to access I only specific the index value (is [1] '3') and Index Of Object (is [2] '5'), i think you are only telling me how to pick the index! And how I can pick the objects?

Comment: Well Well Well I do this! And the correct answer is:  NSString *num = [[myMutableDictionary objectForKey:0] objectAtIndex:0];